# Update LCI inputs from old to newer ecoinvent version

Tags: brightway

I have a big database of activities which in the LCI have activities from an old ecoinvent version.
Is there a fast and easy way to update all the LCIs in the database so that they use a newer version of ecoinvent?

I suppose there might be problems of activities not existing anymore/changed names, if that can be a case, how do you manage that?

I'm new to Brightway so I have no idea about how to do this ;).

Thanks a lot!
Daina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't yet, but we [are working on it](https://github.com/tngTUDOR/brightway2-dbmigrate/). What we normally recommend is to have a reproducible workflow, using whatever data source you prefer. It is very helpful to be able to reproduce your projects if something happens to your computer, and in this case you could re-create your own data and link it to a newer version of whatever database. But you are right, things change from version to version, and this normally requires some metadata on how to handle these changes - hence the library under development.

Comment: Thanks Chris! The link is not working, can you resend it?